# Error: Cannot connect (null)::readyRead() to mythread::readyRead()

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am writing a multithread server but during the compile in "mythraed" class i get the following errors":
1) Cannot connect (null)::readyRead() to mythread::readyRead()
2) Cannot connect (null)::disconnected() to mythread::disconnected()
How should i fix it?
here is my code:

```
void mythread::run()
{

  qDebug() << " Thread started";

connect(m_client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);

connect(m_client, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));


   qDebug() << " Client connected";

     exec();
  }


void mythread::readyRead()

{
  QByteArray Data = m_client->readAll();

  qDebug()<< " Data in: " << Data;

  m_client->write(Data);
}


void mythread::disconnected()
{
  qDebug() << " Disconnected";

  m_client->deleteLater();

  exit(0);
}
```

myclient:

```
myclient::myclient(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{
    QObject::connect(&m_client, SIGNAL(connected()),this, SLOT(startTransfer()));
}


void myclient::start(QString address, quint16 port)
  {

       QHostAddress LocalHost;

        m_client.connectToHost(LocalHost, 6666);
   }


void myclient::startTransfer()
{

  m_client.write("Hello", 5);
}
```

Comment: Where are you creating the `m_client` object?

Comment: in myclient.h :   private:

  QTcpSocket m_client;

Comment: I was referring to the `m_client` in the `mythread` class, not the one in the `myclient` class. Just because they have the same name doesn't mean they're the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `m_client` is `nullptr`.

```
if (m_client) {
  connect(m_client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
}
```

Also you don't need explicitly disconnect your connection, from documentation:

> All signals to and from the object are automatically disconnected, and any pending posted events for the object are removed from the event queue. However, it is often safer to use deleteLater() rather than deleting a QObject subclass directly.

Comment: the error solved. but actually it doesn'n show any message from client... should I add more code for show in server window?

Comment: How do you initialize `m_client`?

Comment: I add "myclient" class to the question

Comment: Your thread will also never end. Consider connecting `m_client`'s `destroyed` signal to `mythread`'s `quit` slot.